# Python Creating Thread Pool for function

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that gives values fast and I have a second function that calculates something from that value which takes around 10-20 seconds. I need to create a thread pool to concurrently run around 40 of the second function at the same time since the first function releases values so fast. How can I go about doing this?
Eg:

```
def function1(): #gives values fast
   while(values not complete):
      newvalue = xyz
      UseAvailableThread(function2(newvalue)) # wait if thread isn't available

def function2(value):
    #computes some data - takes 10-20 seconds
```

I hope the example helps, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: If *function2* is CPU intensive then you should be using Processes rather than Threads. Take a look at ProcessPoolExecutor or ThreadPoolExecutor if it's I/O bound

Comment: Indeed, [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) makes it simpler.

Comment: this actually sounds more like a queue pattern, since one function finishes fast

Comment: if first function run fast then first you could get all values from first function and later use `Multiprocessing.Pool` to run second function with different values at the same time. ie. `p = Multiprocessing.Pool(40)` and `results = p.map(function2, list_with_all_values)`